# Fonte de Dados inválido PDO PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, pdo

Estou tendo problemas na conexão PDO com a base de dados mysql.

**Database_connection.php**:

```
<?php
    class Database_connection {

        private $db_host =  "local";
        private $db_name = "root";
        private $db_user = "user";
        private $db_pass = "pass";
        protected $db_holder;

        protected function open_connection() {
            $this->db_holder = new PDO($this->db_host.$this->db_name, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
        }

        protected function close_connection() {
            $this->db_holder = null;
        }

    }
    ?>
```

Está retornando este erros quando tento fazer um login com usuário e senha:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'invalid 
>   data source name' in Database_connection.php:11  Stack trace:
>   /Database_connection.php(11): PDO->__construct('local', 'user',
>   'pass')   /iis_functions_home.php(9):
>   Database_connection->open_connection()   /log_in_validation.php(13):
>   Iis_functions_home->check_username('username', 'password')   #3 {main}
>   thrown in /Database_connection.php on line 11

Preciso postar mais algum código? Ou o problema está apenas na connexão com o banco de dados?

Comment: Você esta passando seu caminho correto do banco? já tentou se conectar direto pelo banco de dados?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No seu código faltou especificar o driver de qual banco será utilizado, ele é sempre a primeira coisa a se declarar e também a base de dados.

A sintaxe correta é:

```
new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=base', $usuario, $senha);
```

Mude:

```
new PDO($this->db_host
```

Para:

```
new PDO('mysql:host='. $this->db_host .';dbname='.$this->db_name, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
```

Outra alternativa é montar o dsn com a função `sprintf()` no lugar dessa concatenação. Se quiser pode substituir a string `mysql` por uma propriedade.

```
protected function open_connection() {
   $dsn = sprintf('mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s', $this->db_host, $this->db_name);
   $this->db_holder = new PDO($dsn, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
}
```